# Mount job output data as input data for another job in Floydhub

Tags: python, floydhub

I'm trying to follow documentation [here](https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/reusing_output/), [here](https://docs.floydhub.com/guides/data/mounting_data/) and [here](https://help.floydhub.com/using-floydhub/how-can-i-retrieve-the-file-after-data-mounting?utm_content=article_2652005) for Floydhub to use the output of a job as the input data for another job. The 1st and 2nd job are related to 2 different projects.

It's unable to locate my file.

```
No such file or directory: '/output/lemmatized_json.json'
```

**Project 1:**

This project outputs data at the end of the script.

```
import os
if not os.path.exists('output'):
    os.makedirs('output')

with open('output/lemmatized_json.json', 'w') as out_file:
    json.dump(data, out_file)
```

Then its available inside `/files` for that project,

[image]

in the `/output` directory.

[image]

**Project 2:**

Now I run the second project where I want to access that previously saved data.

I run the project with.

```
floyd run --cpu2 --env default \
--data me/projects/lemmatize-json-positions/6/:model \
--message 'train embedding' 'python train_embedding.py'
```

And try to access the data inside it with the following code.

```
file = open('/output/lemmatized_json.json')
```

But I get the above errer `No such file or directory: 'No such file or directory: '/output/lemmatized_json.json'`.

And I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed,

```
file = open('/model/output/lemmatized_json.json')
```